# Adding Objects from a class into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am new to Java and recently wrote a small program that stores cars in a Garage using an Arraylist. Now I have to convert the program to use an Array only. My issue is that I cant directly reference my Car class anymore to create an Array like I could with the Arraylist.

The Car class gets created in the main method based of an input file.

Car class code:

```
public class Car {

 private final String licensePlate;  // license plate number
 private int timesMoved = 0;    // number of moves car has endured


 public Car(String licenseNum)
 {
  licensePlate = licenseNum;
 }


 public String getlicensePlate()
{
  return licensePlate;
 }


public void incrementTimesMoved()   //increment number of moves by 1
{
  timesMoved = timesMoved + 1;
}


public int getTimesMoved()
{
  return timesMoved;
}
```

}

In my Garage class I had this code

```
public class Garage {

private Car carDeparted;

private ArrayList<Car> Garage; // a list of car objects


 public Garage()
 {
    Garage = new ArrayList<>() ; 
 }
}
```

This worked really well so I tried the same Idea with an Array but am not doing it wrong

New Garage class Code

```
public class Garage {

private Car carDeparted;

Car [] Garage;  // a list of car objects

/**
  Constructs a garage with no cars.
*/
public Garage()
 {
    Garage = new Car [10]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < Garage.length; i++)
    Garage[i] = new Car();

 }
```

Garage[i] = new Car(); says error because I need the string parameter to populate it but when I had the arraylist I did not have that issue.

I need it so the Array stores up to 10 cars in it based on the car class that is created.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: In the Arraylist version you never actually add a car. So from Car() was never called in this version?

Comment: You are simply creating an ArrayList with Car objects, you're not adding any car to your list.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the compiler as much as you are confusing us and possibly also yourself with your naming of variables. Follow common java practice and let instance variables start with a lowercase letter and also try to avoid the same name for a instance variable as a class when the variable is of a different type.

Comment: In the car class you have constructor  public Car(String licenseNum); 
 And in you arraylist you created arraylist only and not added any car object

Comment: Got it I see now thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to do to much in the constructor, create a separate class for managing the garage and the cars or for simplicity add a `main` method to your `Garage` class.

Furthermore add a public method for adding cars to the garage. This is how a `main` method could look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Garage garage = new Garage(10); // 10 is the number of cars that can park in the garage
    Car car1 = new Car("ABC123456");
    garage.add(car1);
    Car car2 = new Car("DEF5467467");
    garage.add(car2);
   //more code to test your classes
}
```

Note that this code will work independently of the way you store your cars, in an array or an ArrayList if you do it right. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It is becouse it construct of car accepts string of u want to add car without licence plate overload the car construct er without string licencenum argument or add random string in ur for loop

Answer (score 1):

Vs97 is right you never initialized the Car class in the ArrayList version. In your array version you are attempting to initialize the car but you aren’t passing the required licensePlate parameter.

```
Garage[i] = new Car();
```

Should be

```
Garage[i] = new Car(“plate number”);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create a array like that ,
you need to add a empty parameter constucter to the car class

```
  public Car() {
    licensePlate ="";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is duo To the constructor As you can see in your  Car.java

```
         public Car(String licenseNum)
        {
           licensePlate = licenseNum;
        }
```

The constructor you are using need a String input , try a constructor without input this should work .

Answer (score 1):

In the ArrayList version, you have just declared the ArrayList but not store any car object inside it. But in array version of your code, you are trying to store car object inside it, which can't be done at this moment according to your code.
So you just do,

```
public Garage()
{
   Garage = new Car [10]; 
}
```

And when you need to add Car object inside array, you create object of Car class using `new` keyword. For example,

```
Garage[0] = new Car("abc");
```